# Html 5 input type date not showing placeholder on chrome mobile

Tags: html, mobile-chrome

I am using HTML 5 input type date in my web app. On chrome desktop input type date shows placeholder 'dd/mm/yyyy' but on chrome mobile .. it is blank. 
my chrome mobile version is 65.0.3325.109
what may be the possible reason?

```html
<input type="date" id="special-input-date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" />
```

Comment: I assume only valid data for that input can take the role of a placeholder. Try `placeholder="1970-01-01"` instead and check if that shows up.

Comment: @connexo i changed it.. it still shows nothing on phone and on desktop .. it shows dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Maybe your pattern comes in the way? It does allow only digits and dashes, not letters and slashes.

Comment: i removed pattern.. still the same

Comment: @connexo when i put value="1970-01-01" it shows that value..but i want a placeholder. I think will have to use some css trick to mimic it.

Comment: can you use this code to do that `$( "input#special-input-date" ).load(function() { $( this ).attr( "placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy" ); });`